# Jquery removeClass, addClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having poblems with the removeClass and addClass function. I am trying to change a font awesome class when a dropdown is clicked open. I have attempted several times to make this work but I think I must be overlooking something.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="cssmenu"class="col-xs-12 left">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
       <li><a href='#'><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
       <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
```

And here is my Jquery code where I am trying to delete the class and add another one:

```
$('#cssmenu ul li a i').on('click', function() {
    $('#cssmenu ul li a i').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
    $(this).addClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

Thanks for having a look :) Btw I am looking for clues and not answers, since I am trying to learn Jquery.

Comment: try to put alert in `click` do you get `alert`? Is `cssmenu` dynamically added in `DOM`?

Comment: Remove the `i` from the on click `$('#cssmenu ul li a').on('click', function() {$('#cssmenu ul li a i').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
        $(this).addClass('fa-caret-down');
});`

Comment: this is wanting you to click on the `<i>` tag, you're probably clicking on the anchor.

Comment: Are you actually adding content to your `i` tag?  Pretty hard to click it if you're not.

Comment: I changed the previous code to this : $('#cssmenu ul li').on('click', function(). Now i get a alert before I didn't . It seems to remove the class but not add the caret-down class.

Comment: you have to use `$(this).find("i").addClass('fa-caret-down');`

Comment: jsfiddlle would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the click event on the list item:

```
$('#cssmenu ul li').on('click', function() {
        $('#cssmenu ul li a i').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
        $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude did not think i needed to use the .find class to add the fa class!

Comment: Your welcome. Your function does work, but only when you click on the `i`. By changing that to the `li` you make a bigger 'click area'. Then you need to *find*  the `i` inside the element.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `click` on the element `<i>`, which apparently you are not clicking. Try using `click` on the anchor `<a>` tag and change the class on the `<i>` contained in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cssmenu ul li a').on('click', function() {
        $('#cssmenu ul li a i').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
        $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

Comment: inside click function it should be possible to get i element using $('i',this)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#cssmenu ul li a i').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('fa-caret-down').siblings().removeClass('fa-caret-right');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$('#cssmenu ul li.has-sub').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-caret-right').addClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the clues you mentioned, you may want to look into jQuery's toggleClass() method:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/